# Rails prevent before_action on specific routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to prevent `before_action` from running on specific routes? Say, post routes that do api actions? My action currently does this

```
before_action :setContext

    def setContext
        @site = Site.find_by!(host: request.subdomain)
        @page = Page.find_by!(site_id: @site.id, slug: request.path)
    end
```

And on api routes, the Page find 404's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `only` and `except` options:

```
before_action :setContext, only: [:show, :edit]
before_action :setContext, except: [:new, :destroy]
```

You can also use the `if:` or `unless:` option with a lambda:

```
before_action :setContext, if: -> { request.format.html? }
before_action :setContext, unless: -> { request.format.json? }
```

You can also use `skip_before_action` which is useful if the `before_action` is defined in the parent class:

```
class ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!
end

class ThingsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:index, :show]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to check for `request.format.json?`.

```
before_action :setContext

def setContext
  unless request.format.json?
    @site = Site.find_by!(host: request.subdomain)
    @page = Page.find_by!(site_id: @site.id, slug: request.path)
  end
end
```

Another way to use `except` with `before_action`.

```
before_action :setContext, except: [:api_actions] # put all comma separated routes in place of api_actions

def setContext
  @site = Site.find_by!(host: request.subdomain)
  @page = Page.find_by!(site_id: @site.id, slug: request.path)
end
```